# PrimeFaces datatable shrinks

Tags: css, primefaces, datatable

Please I need help, how do I make PrimeFaces datatable be consistent in display on Firefox.

On Firefox the datatable shrinks are displayed below.
[image]

On chrome is shows well, see below.
[image]

Please how to I make firefox display well.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think its a PrimeFaces problem. Maybe you can try and solve it using css.

```
<p:dataTable styleClass="myDataTable">

.myDataTable{
        table-layout: fixed;
}
```